# I need to unstack or pivot keeping duplicated index

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to unstack a column but also keep the duplicated index.

```
df = pd.DataFrame( data={'Order': ['123', '123','123'],\
'Ticket': ['987', '987','987'],'Status': ['Added', 'Removed', 'Added'], \
'Dates': ['2016-02-15', '2017-12-24', '2018-01-24']})
```

I tried this:

```
df.pivot_table(index=['Order', 'Ticket' ], columns='Status', values='Dates', aggfunc= 'first')
```

and also tried this:

```
df.insert(0, 'count', df.groupby(['Order', 'Ticket']).cumcount())
df.pivot(index='count', columns='Status', values='Dates')
```

Looking to get result like this:
[image: 1]

```
 # Order    Ticket      Added        Removed
 # 123      987        2016-02-15   2017-12-24
 # 123      987        2018-01-24    NaT
```

and later calculate the duration.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
df.insert(0, "count", df.groupby(["Order", "Ticket", "Status"]).cumcount())
df.set_index(["count", "Order", "Ticket", "Status"]).unstack()


                                    Dates
              Status       Added    Removed
count   Order   Ticket      
0       123      987    2016-02-15  2017-12-24
1       123      987    2018-01-24  NaN
```

Comment: Thank you, but the expected result is to have only 2 rows returned to calculate the duration.

Comment: yes, the output has two rows. how many rows have you got?

Comment: My apologies. I needed to refresh. It is  also 1 am now haha. You are absolutely right and thank you SO much! @sammywemmy